# Impala ODBC Driver Syntax Error (Encountered DECIMAL LITERAL)

Tags: sql, odbc, pyodbc, impala

I'm attempting to do a simple INSERT INTO statement on an Impala table that has the following schema:

- field1 (date)
- field2 (string)
- field3 (string)
- field4 (string)
- field5 (string)
- field6 (bigint)

I am using Impala pyODBC drivers to do this. Here's my query

INSERT INTO testdb.mydata VALUES('2018-06-20', 'field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4', 'field5', 1000000)

However I keep getting the following error and I don't understand why! It's an AnalysisException and Syntax error which is super general and I just cannot pinpoint where the issue is. I am following the format specified by Cloudera's documentation here: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_insert.html

> AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 1:undefined: ...INTO
>   testdb.mydata VALUES('2018-06... ^ Encountered: DECIMAL LITERAL
>   Expected: ADD, ALTER, AND, ARRAY, AS, ASC, BETWEEN, BIGINT, BINARY,
>   BLOCK_SIZE, BOOLEAN, CACHED, CASCADE, CHANGE, CHAR, COMMENT,
>   COMPRESSION, CROSS, DATE, DATETIME, DECIMAL, DEFAULT, DESC, DIV, REAL,
>   DROP, ELSE, ENCODING, END, FLOAT, FOLLOWING, FROM, FULL, GROUP,
>   IGNORE, HAVING, ILIKE, IN, INNER, INTEGER, IREGEXP, IS, JOIN, LEFT,
>   LIKE, LIMIT, LOCATION, MAP, NOT, NULL, NULLS, OFFSET, ON, OR, ORDER,
>   PARTITION, PARTITIONED, PRECEDING, PRIMARY, PURGE, RANGE, RECOVER,
>   REGEXP, RENAME, REPLACE, RESTRICT, RIGHT, RLIKE, ROW, ROWS, SELECT,
>   SET, SMALLINT, SORT, STORED, STRAIGHT_JOIN, STRING, STRUCT,
>   TABLESAMPLE, TBLPROPERTIES, THEN, TIMESTAMP, TINYINT, TO, UNCACHED,
>   UNION, USING, VALUES, VARCHAR, WHEN, WHERE, WITH, COMMA, IDENTIFIER
>   CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error\n (110)

I also tried referencing the column names as follows:

INSERT INTO testdb.mydata(field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6) VALUES(....) but that yielded the same error message.

Other answers on here don't seem to address this specific error. Any guidance would be super appreciated, thanks!

Comment: try to replace `'2018-06-20'` with `date'2018-06-20'`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did and it still throws the same error :( I tried changing field1's datatype to string to see if there was some issue with the date type but no luck.